# adding an image with JQUERY and after a text box is blank

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add an image after a button is clicked.  However, I can't seem to get the attribute of an image to show a different .png file.  Basically if the text is blank then show a green check else show a red icon.  I want to validate text then validate the expression to be in an email format.  But for now I can't seem to get the image to change when a text box is null.

Here is what I'm loading at the beginning of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#imgEmail').hide();
  });
</script>
```

Here is my logic after the button is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateText() {

      if (!$("#tbEmail").val()) {
          $('#imgEmail').attr('src', '../Images/Red-Error-Icon.png');
      } else {              
          $('#imgEmail').attr('src', '../Images/Green-Check-Icon.png');        
      }
  }
</script>
```

Here is the HTML for the texbox, image and the button:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<img id="imgEmail" alt="">

<asp:Button ID="btnSignUp" runat="server" OnClientClick="validateText()"/>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you also need to show this image?

```
$('#imgEmail').show();
```

Comment: I think you're going to have trouble when this posts back, because that's a page request. I know very little asp, but when the page reloads your $(document)ready() function is going to fire, hiding the element.  This will overwrite the show you've put in the validation.  Maybe you should check if the image has a source attribute set before hiding it?

Answer (score 1):

You have changed the attribute but the image is still hidden.

You need to add $('#imgEmail').show();

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function validateText() {

          if (!$("#tbEmail").val()) {
              $('#imgEmail').attr('src', '../Images/Red-Error-Icon.png');
          } else {              
              $('#imgEmail').attr('src', '../Images/Green-Check-Icon.png');        
          }
    $('#imgEmail').show();


      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  This worked but for some reason the the picture does not display after the postback.  I have tried putting the image and the textbox in an update panel but that doesn't seem to work.  I'm using .NET with Telerik controls.  I have tried using the .NET update panel versus Telerik's update panel.

Comment: I would recommend setting the CSS property display:none; instead of using jQuery to hide the element on page load. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks again! I have created a style of the following: .style7 { width: 16px; height: 16px; display:none; } and applied this style then I tried either addClass or toggleClass that calls a different style that does not have display:none.  But still doesn't seem to work.  I do see the image change appropriately but after postback the image comes back blank.

Comment: OK here is what I had to do besides using the toggleClass.  I had to put the image element outside of the update panel.